# What are the different worlds' size in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

In Terraria, you can choose the world's size when creating a new one.

The current version of the game offers three choices : small, medium and large.

What is the size of the world for each option (in blocks)?

Comment: Nitpick: It's small, medium, and large. ;-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A quick little table of world dimensions in tile sizes

- Small - (1200,4200)
- Medium - (1800,6300)
- Large - (2400,8400)

These dimensions were retrieved via the Map Renderer tool from the Terraria Online forums.

Hope this helps

Comment: How many small squares made a tile?

Comment: @Drake One small square == One tile :)

Comment: Now that I got a depth meter, I can say that 1 tile = 2 feet

Comment: @Drake That caught me by surprise initially as well, I was down in the hell area and my depth meter said 1300 while I was on a Small  map :)