# How far and at what height are dungeons?

Tags: terraria

According to [Terraria Wiki](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Dungeon)

> The Dungeon is one of the highest
>   level "biomes" in the game. It is
>   either on the right or the left side
>   of the map and can be in a variety of
>   colors, including green, pink, purple,
>   and blue.

but how far are dungeons from first spawn points? Are they at ground level, in air or underground?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the example output from [UberJumper's map viewer](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/terraria-map-viewer.4226/).  The large, purple, angular structure on the left is the dungeon.

From what I've seen, it is a typical example.  Dungeons start at ground level, run more or less vertically down into the rock layer, and then branch out, becoming mazelike.  They may extend into the lower rock layer (where some lava starts appearing), but never into the underworld (where the sea of lava is).  Dungeons are **always** underground, but are also **always** accessible from the surface.

Your spawn point is dead center in the world (horizontally, that is) and the dungeon spawns as far as it can towards either edge of the map (but never both; you only get one dungeon).  This means that it is about as far away from the spawn as it is possible to get.  Plus, you could always find you've gone the wrong way and be on the opposite side of the map.  (If you find the jungle before you find the dungeon, you've gone the wrong way.)

Comment: Very nice screenshot at the link you posted, it gives a good overview of what to expect on Terraria world.

Answer (score 6):

- Dungeons are at the edge of the map - Take the distance from [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22389/what-are-the-different-worlds-size-in-terraria) and halve it for a rough idea.
- The entrance is at ground level; the dungeon itself goes a long way underground.

Comment: Removing my previous comment of dungeons extending all the way down. I just saw a mid to large sized map where it only went half way down.